# GetWidthPoint not returning expected value

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm using the iTextSharp to export reports to PDF and I have a table with all content that I need.

I want to give columns width based on the most wide text of each column, but the `GetWidtPoint()` method returns text width that I'm not expecting and the column content jumps to the next line.

Below, there is an example about the calculus of the header text width. I put all my table header inside an array first.

```
Dim ColSize(10) as single 
Dim Ck as Chunk

For I = 0 to Colsize.getUpperBound(0)
        Ck = new Chunk(Data(I),myFont)
        Ck.SetCharacterSpacing(1)
        Colsize(I) = Ck.GetWidthPoint
Next I
```

Finally, the table declaration...

```
Dim T as new PdfPtable(11)
T.HorizontalAligment = 0
T.WidthPercentage = 100
T.SpacingBefore = 3
T.setWidths(Colsize)
```

An example about issue:

Through the calculus method that I used, the `GetWidthPoint()` returns 33 points to "Produto" word, but if i set the column width to 33f so I cant show this text only in the first line. To Show the entire word in the same line, I need to set the column width to 55f.

When i print the text in the cell...

```
Dim Cell as new PdfpCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(Data(I,X),Font)))
T.addCell(cell)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget the cell margins, they are 2 by default, 4 in total. You are not posting the way you are creating the cell but I'm guessing that it's introducing even more margins.

Comment: then... what i must do about this? What i've need to do?

Comment: You are also setting the relative widths of the column instead of absolute widths, call `PdfPTable.SetTotalWidth()` instead.

Comment: i've changed Pdftable.SetWidths by the SetTotalWidth expression... passing the ColSize array in the parameter. But the columns width are wrong yet.